# Number of comparisons in selection sort?

Tags: java, arrays, class, sorting

My program deals with the number of comparisons using selection sort. It returns the wrong number of comps. Where is comp going wrong?

My demo:

```
    ArrayI[] ints = new ArrayI[5];


    ints[0] = new ArrayInts(3);
    ints[1] = new ArrayInts(9);
    ints[2] = new ArrayInts(6);
    ints[3] = new ArrayInts(1);
    ints[4] = new ArrayInts(2);




    SelectionSort.selectionSort(myInts);

    System.out.println(" ");

    System.out.println("Sorted array: ");

    for(ArrayI ints:myInts){
        System.out.println(ints);
    }

    System.out.println(" ");

    System.out.println("Number of comparisons: " + SelectionSort2.selectionSort2(ints));
```

Comment: Why do you have a different method for counting number of comparison? Can't you do it in the first method itself?

Comment: And what's the point of that `ArrayInts` class? Why can't you simply use `Integer`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the number of comparisons using insertion sort?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560458/what-is-the-number-of-comparisons-using-insertion-sort)

Comment: @seh Not a duplicate - the questions relate to two different sorting methods.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I saw that it was the same author for each, and thought that he posted it twice. I retracted that vote. I will vote to close it for a different reason.

Answer (score 4):

That is because, you are incrementing the comparison outside the inner loop. So the value of comparison would be equals to the number of times your outer loop runs. Move the increment to inner loop:

And you really don't need the `min` variable. You can rather move the swapping logic inside the `if` block. You should modify your code to:

```
for(int index = 0; index < data.length-1; index++) {

    for(int scan = index+1; scan < data.length; scan++) {
        comparisons++;  // Each inner loop does one comparison

        if(data[scan].compareTo(data[min]) < 0) {
            temp = data[scan];
            data[scan] = data[index];
            data[index] = temp;
        }
    }   
}
```

I don't really understand your point of creating an `ArrayInts` class. That's totally unnecessary. You could have simply used `Integer` wrapper class.
And just for your information, you have an [`Arrays#sort(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) method, which does the sorting for you.